# Size of objects in bytes, when not aligned with the architecture?

Tags: c++, byte

Assume I'm on Windows x64. Also assume I have this 9-Byte long example class:

```
class Example{
public:
   double x;
   bool y;

   void someFunction();
}
```

If I go ahead and make an array of 4 Example objects, I will be using memory with 36 bytes. My questions are these:

- Since I'm on a x64 architecture, does that mean I will have 4 unusable bytes in the end of the array? (36 + 4 = 40 = 5 * 8bytes) And by unusable I mean that my program is not going to use that place of memory, as long as the array exists.
- If I compile my c++ program for x32 and the above is true... Do I still have 4 unusable bytes? Is that dependent on what architecture the program runs?
- Are there any cases that objects would **not** use a length of memory that's equal to the size sum of their member variables?

**Disclaimer: Not computer scientist / engineer. Easy answers please!** Thank you!

Edit 1: The example class is not 9 bytes, it's 16 when used with sizeof(), but in array context, addresses of objects are 9 bytes apart.

Comment: *Also assume I have this 9-Byte long example class:* -- Have you actually computed what `sizeof(Example)` is?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You are right for correcting me, I was looking at the addresses of the objects while in arrays and I saw they were 9 bytes apart... I edited it in the question.

Comment: 9 bytes apart doesn't mean that it's size is 9 bytes unless it's fundamental types.

Comment: @김선달 Could you elaborate with an example?

Comment: How did you create your array? And btw, size of a struct(including clas) is multiples of biggest size of it's members. In your case, `double` is 8 bytes, so your class is at least 16bytes.

Comment: @김선달 I did `Example x = new Example[3];` and then used `std::cout` to count the space between addresses and it was 9 bytes. Doing this with a static array, it gives 16 bytes instead. I also replaced double with float and my class is now 8 bytes long. So the architecture is completely irrelevant?

Comment: @gzarpapis Size of integer types that's size is not specified and pointers are relevant to the architecture. But in your case, there's only `bool` and `double`, so it's size will be same. Size of dynamically allocated object's size can be different with it's real size. Statically allocated object's size is always reliable.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing you can be really sure of is that sizeof(Example) is a constant, and is large enough to (at least) contain the values.

When defining the a class or struct you actually only specify two things: The types of the individual members, and their order. The compiler is basically free to do the memory representation in any way it wants, as long as it follows those two.

In most cases the compiler will add padding so all members are aligned for easy access, meaning for instance that the offset within the class of a double will be a multiple of 8 bytes.
("Easy access" can be a bit of a rabbit-hole to get into, which is outside of this answer).

Arrays are aligned with the same size as in non-array cases: `sizeof(Example[4]) == sizeof(Example)*4`
This also means that in most cases the size of Example will be padded to be a multiple of 8 bytes, because then all objects in an array are aligned for easy access.

Note that there are possibilities with preprocessor pragmas like `#pragma pack` to specify how the compiler should do all this, but they are all compiler-specific and not portable, so I suggest avoiding them.

In short: Don't assume anything about size, but instead use `sizeof()` where needed.
Even better: Avoid using the binary size anywhere, as the compiler will take care about it in most cases and it will often make the code more complicated than need be.